# SignalR : cannot access a disposed object error

Tags: asp.net-core, signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client, asp.net-core-signalr

I have a hub like this:

```
public class LockerHub : Hub
{
    private Timer signalRTimer;

    public LockerHub()
    {
        double interval = 5000; 
        signalRTimer = new Timer(interval);
        signalRTimer.Elapsed += OnSignalRTimerElapsed;
        signalRTimer.Start();
    }

    private void OnSignalRTimerElapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        GetAllStatusModel();
    }

    [HubMethodName("GetAllStatusModel")]
    public void GetAllStatusModel()
    {
        Clients.All.SendAsync("AllStatusModel", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Locker.LockerBoxesState, Formatting.Indented));
    }
}
```

At the same time, I have client code as shown here for testing:

```
static async void MyMethod()
{
    var hubUrl = "....";

    var connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
        .WithUrl(hubUrl)
        .Build();

    connection.Closed += async (exception) =>
    {
        await Task.Delay(5000);
        await connection.StartAsync();
    };

    connection.On<string>("AllStatusModel", (message) =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"New Message: {message}");
    });

    try
    {
        await connection.StartAsync();

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {          
    }
    finally
    {
    }
}
```

My aim is to send a message to all connected clients in a certain period of time, but as I mentioned in the description, I get an error. I couldn't come up with a solution to the problem. Can you help me ?

Comment: Could you share the minimal sample for us checking? It would be faster to help you and please don't forget to hide the sensitive info.